# How to do Bulk Upwrite in Pymongo

Tags: pymongo

I currently have this code which loops through every row in my mongoDB collection table, and either inserts a row or updates a row with new data (depending on whether todays date and studentID is there or not):

```
for rowindex, row in InsertionData.iterrows():
    record = row.to_dict()
    record['date'] = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(0, 0))
    collection.replace_one({'student': row.get('student'), 'date': record['date']}, record, upsert=True)
```

However, I was wondering whether there was a way to do a bulk upsert?

My idea is that it would loop through all of the records to be updated, create the update script and add it to an operations array. Then once it either runs out of records or it reaches 5000, it runs a bulkWrite function to Mongo, which basically sends one request to the mongo server rather than 5000 single requests. 
This would make it much faster, as the biggest slow down is communication between server's rather than the actual update function itself.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this in python/pymongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Bulk Write Operations`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#bulk-write-operations).

Create a list and add each updates as a `ReplaceOne`, e.g.

```
operations = []
for rowindex, row in InsertionData.iterrows():
    record = row.to_dict()
    record['date'] = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(0, 0))
    operations.append(ReplaceOne({'student': row.get('student'), 'date': record['date']}, record, upsert=True))

collection.bulk_write(operations)
```